# calculate year difference from field - start, today, e end

Tags: php

this code calculates the difference of years between fields
"Start"
and
today.
I have another field
"End".
I wish it when it is compiled
"Start"
and
"End"
account stopped today,
if instead only compiled
"Start"
resume counting with today

```
<?php

$start = $row['start'];

$dateOfStart = $start;
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$diff = abs($dateOfStart - $today);

$a=explode(' ',$diff);
if($a[0]>1){
    $y=$a[0]."  Years  ";
}else{$y=$diff."  Year";}


echo   '<font color="blue">'. $y . '&nbsp' . In . '&nbsp' . The . '&nbsp' . Business . '</font>';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$start = $row['start'];

$dateOfStart = $start;
if(isset($row['end'])){
   $dateOfEnd = $row['end'];
}
else{
   $dateOfEnd = date("Y-m-d");
}
$diff = abs($dateOfStart - $dateOfEnd);

/* NOTE: the value of $diff at that time is an integer, 
so you don't need explode ??. In fact $a[0] will 
always be >= 0, and is equal to $diff, so you should 
consider checking the end of your script to... */

$a=explode(' ',$diff);
if($a[0]>1){
    $y=$a[0]."  Years  ";
}else{$y=$diff."  Year";}

/* NOTE: Why not simply this instead: */
$y=$diff."  Year"; 
if($diff>1){
    $y.="s";
}

echo   '<font color="blue">'. $y . '&nbsp' . In . '&nbsp' . The . '&nbsp' . Business . '</font>';

?>
```

Comment: `$diff` is an integer returned from `abs`, it can't be submitted to `explode` , but hey thanks for explaining what the OP was tying to do.

Comment: @Accountantم Thanks for pointing that out! I added a note about it.